# Groupby irrespective of column order

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe on which i want to apply a groupby function on multiple columns but i want to do this irrespective of the column order. For example if the columns to group by are called "ID1" and "ID2" i want to groupby "ID1" and "ID2" and then .max() the rest of the columns per row but not only for the combination ID1/ID2 but also ID2/ID1. So if i have the following dataframe:

| ID1 | ID2 | Value1 | Value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 5678 | 1 | 0 |
| 5678 | 1234 | 0 | 1 |

And it has to become:

| ID1/ID2 | Value1 | Value2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234/5678 | 1 | 1 |

new = df.groupby(["ID1", "ID2"]).max().reset_index()

but i think this only groups the combination ID1/ID2 and not ID2/ID2 also in the same row.